# Do any sites have local badges?

Tags: support, badges, stack-exchange

Are all the badges available across all network sites, or do any SE sites have site specific (local) badges?

(Excluding tag badges)

Answer (score 7):

Stack Apps has 2 extra [badges](https://stackapps.com/badges); they even come with free rep. Sadly, they're now impossible to attain:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The site with the most specific badges is probably [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). You can look at their [badge list](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges). These badges are unique to this site due to his specificity.

Badges about referring to a commitment:

- [Activist](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/209/activist)
- [Campaigner](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/208/campaigner)
- [Promoter](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/207/promoter)
- [Lobbyist](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/206/lobbyist)

Badges about following through a commitment:

- [Loyalist](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/212/loyalist)
- [Adherent](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/211/adherent)
- [Upholder](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/210/upholder)

Badges for having followers to a proposal:

- [Revolution](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/22/revolution)
- [Movement](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/21/movement)
- [Grassroot](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/20/grassroots)
- [Caucus](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/200/caucus)

Others:

- [Founder](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/204/founder)
- [Pioneer](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/205/pioneer)
- [Filibuster](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/7/filibuster)
- [Analyst](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/94/analyst)